# Perl - How to suppress output from a forked child process

Tags: perl, process, fork, stdout

I have a perl script which has to make a call to tar within an exec.

```
exec("tar zcf /tmp/mytarball.gz directoryToTarBall > /dev/null 2>&1" or die ("$!")
```

This is a child process which I have forked and in the meantime, I'm monitoring the progress of the tar by writing a full stop to STDOUT.  The problem I have is that I don't want tar to be verbose when creating the tarball - i dont want output to be echoed to stdout....I just want the progress counter (the full stops) echoing back to screen.  I thought I could pass a `>/dev/null 2>&1` within the exec command but that didn't work.

Any ideas greatly received. Thanks and regards

Comment: Your code snippet has mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `exec LIST` form to avoid surprises due to shell quoting. This also requires performing the redirection that the shell would do for you.

```
use 5.10.0;  # //

my $pid = fork // die "$0: fork: $!";   # / fix Stack Overflow highlighting
if ($pid) {
  waitpid $pid, 0 or die "$0: waitpid: $!";
  warn "$0: child exited abnormally" if $?;
  print ".\n";  # done!
}
else {
  open STDOUT, ">",  "/dev/null" or die "$0: open: $!";
  open STDERR, ">&", \*STDOUT    or exit 1;
  exec "tar", "zcf", "/tmp/mytarball.gz", "directoryToTarBall";
  exit 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Looks pretty good to me so I will try this out when I get a chance and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e "exec(\"ls >/dev/null\")"
```

Works for me atleast. Trying `2>&1`

This convoluted mess works as well

```
perl -e "exec(\"ls >&2 2>&1 1>/dev/null\")"
```

Even this works, thought it probably shouldnt

```
perl -e "exec(\"ls 1>&2 >/dev/null\")"
```

Where are you stuck exactly?